# ¿Cómo ordenar cuadros sin que se pierda la posición con css?

Tags: php, html, css, html5, css3

Estoy generando desde php los datos que van a ir varios cuadros, este es mi código como lo genero:

```
<?
    $productos=array(
        array("nombre"=>"food", "imagen"=>"http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food", "precio"=>"50"),
        array("nombre"=>"sports", "imagen"=>"http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports", "precio"=>"332"),
        array("nombre"=>"este es 333 nombre largo", "imagen"=>"http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city", "precio"=>"636"),
        array("nombre"=>"city extra super super largo", "imagen"=>"http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract", "precio"=>"485"),
        array("nombre"=>"business", "imagen"=>"http://lorempixel.com/200/200/business", "precio"=>"257"),
        array("nombre"=>"nightlife nombre super super largo", "imagen"=>"http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nightlife", "precio"=>"156"),
        array("nombre"=>"fashion", "imagen"=>"http://lorempixel.com/200/200/fashion", "precio"=>"700"),

        array("nombre"=>"food", "imagen"=>"http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food", "precio"=>"222"),
        array("nombre"=>"sports", "imagen"=>"http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports", "precio"=>"635"),
        array("nombre"=>"este es 333", "imagen"=>"http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city", "precio"=>"834"),
        array("nombre"=>"city nombre extra super super largo", "imagen"=>"http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract", "precio"=>"944"),
        array("nombre"=>"business", "imagen"=>"http://lorempixel.com/200/200/business", "precio"=>"2347"),
        array("nombre"=>"nightlife", "imagen"=>"http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nightlife", "precio"=>"1689"),
        array("nombre"=>"fashion", "imagen"=>"http://lorempixel.com/200/200/fashion", "precio"=>"278"),
    );
    foreach($productos as $producto => $contenido){
?>
<div class="app_lista_item oh rod">
    <img src="<?=$contenido['imagen']?>" class="app_lista_item_imagen db rod" />
    <div class="app_lista_item_nombre"><?=$contenido['nombre']?></div>
</div>
<?
    }
?>
```

esto es un ejemplo sin php:
https://jsfiddle.net/traslapc/e20cw6sh/

como veran se desposicionan los cuadros, no estan alineados:
[image: desposicion cuadros]

lo que me gustaria lograr es esto:
[image: cuadros posicionados]

primero que esten alineados como en la imagen de la izquierda, y segundo, que cada dos cuadros me genere un cuadro que ocupe el tamaño de 4 cuadros. ¿Como puedo realizar lo mencionado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es:

- Maquetar tus imágenes y sus textos en una rejilla con CSS Grid
- Al contenedor padre le damos una dispocisión de grid
- También le damos un ancho definido para respetar como lo muestras en la imagen
- Establecemos que el contenido se divida en 2 columnas ocupando una fracción igual de espacio cada una de ellas
- Le damos un width de un 100% a las imágenes para que ocupen todo el espacio disponible de su contenedor
- Aunque los párrafos mas largo de algunos imágenes se seguirán viendo completos, estos no afectarán a los otros elementos de la rejilla

Código:

```html
    <style>
      .app_lista_contenido {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .app_lista_item {
        border: 1px solid;
      }
    
      img {
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    
    <div class="app_lista_contenido ma oh">
      <div class="app_lista_item oh rod">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food" class="app_lista_item_imagen db rod" />
        <div class="app_lista_item_nombre">food</div>
      </div>
      <div class="app_lista_item oh rod">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food" class="app_lista_item_imagen db rod" />
        <div class="app_lista_item_nombre">food</div>
      </div>
      <div class="app_lista_item oh rod">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food" class="app_lista_item_imagen db rod" />
        <div class="app_lista_item_nombre">food</div>
      </div>
      <div class="app_lista_item oh rod">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food" class="app_lista_item_imagen db rod" />
        <div class="app_lista_item_nombre">food</div>
      </div>
      <div class="app_lista_item oh rod">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food" class="app_lista_item_imagen db rod" />
        <div class="app_lista_item_nombre">food</div>
      </div>
      <div class="app_lista_item oh rod">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food" class="app_lista_item_imagen db rod" />
        <div class="app_lista_item_nombre">food very food food very foodfood very food</div>
      </div>
      <div class="app_lista_item oh rod">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food" class="app_lista_item_imagen db rod" />
        <div class="app_lista_item_nombre">food</div>
      </div>
      <div class="app_lista_item oh rod">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food" class="app_lista_item_imagen db rod" />
        <div class="app_lista_item_nombre">food</div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
```

Cómo te dejaba en la zona de comentarios, puedes indicar la posición que en tu cuadrícula ocupen los elementos, siguiendo esto:

- Elige el o los elementos a reubicar
- Con grid-row y grid-column podemos indicar dónde inicien y terminen pues

  - Reciben una pareja de valores: n / m para el inicio y termino de la ubicación en filas y columnas según corresponda
- Esta pareja de valores son una sintaxis abreviada de:

  - grid-column-start
  - grid-column-end
  - grid-row-start
  - grid-row-end

Dejo [este enlace como fuente de consulta](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

Comment: gracias, muy interesante lo del grid, logre aprender algo nuevo del css, utilice php verificando los números pares e impar, con ello conseguí agregar uno u mas items nuevos entre los actuales, y con ayuda de "grid-column" logre formar el cuadro de dos filas y columnas, prácticamente se convirtió en una tabla el div, solo que sin muchas etiquetas, desde hoy en día el float ya no tiene relevancia para mi <3

Comment: aunque me pregunto, habrá alguna forma de aplicar el "grid-column" en algunos de los items actuales? así descarto el php, por ejemplo, el contenedor tiene 8 items, seleccionar dos al azar y luego aplicar el "grid-column", estos dos item seleccionados tendrían que venir después de un item par, osea luego de 2, 4, 6, es posible?

Comment: simplemente hermoso! desconocía el "grid-row", con ello pude completar lo que quería, ya ni siquiera hace falta que utilice lo del numero par/impar para alterar el posicionamiento en el foreach, simplemente uso rand de php para establecer la posición al azar en el css https://jsfiddle.net/traslapc/1zu70r6o/ , de verdad, muchísimas gracias, me evitaste todo un dolor de cabeza con php o js <3